# Remove uiimage atindex with a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have about 15 `UIImages` in a `UIView` that have gesture recognizer. When u touch one and pan a little, it comes to the front of the others by inserting subview under another view that I have permanently in the front.

I am looking for a way to make a button that removes whichever `UIImage` is at the front.

I have tried `removeFromSuperview`. But could only call `UIImage` by name and not by index position.

And `exchangeSubview` for `subViewAtIndex`.

But it does what it says and exchanges. But I can’t find a way to remove or hide instead.

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a simpler approach. When you move a view to the front to let the user begin dragging it, save the view to a `weak` instance variable `frontImageView`.

When the user taps on the button, invoke code like this:

```
[frontImageView removeFromSuperview];
```

### Edit:

Note that that approach would let the user remove an image view after they have dragged it, but only once. Once you've removed an image view, you'd have to tap another one in order to be able to remove it. If you want to be able to remove the top image view regardless of whether it's been tapped/dragged or not, you'd need to check your parent view controller's subviews array.

If the view that contains all your image views is called `containerView`, the code might look like this:

```
[containerView.subviews.lastObject removeFromSuperview];
```

That second line would let the user tap the remove button repeatedly and delete one image after another without having to tap on a new image to select it.

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C, not Swift.

Comment: Oops. So it is. Time to edit my answer...

Comment: Thank you! I embeded the images into UIViews and added the gestures to the UIView and it worked!

Comment: If you get the answer vote it up. This how u thank him for his effort and time

Comment: @NithinChandran the OP doesn't have enough reputation to up-vote yet. He did accept it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the hash of image you want to remove then compare the hash with the hash of image in UIImageView if it is same the removeFromSuperview else move to next view.

**OR** try comparing the the data generated by UIImagePNGRepresentation, it should return true if you are passing same images to convert into data.

```
- (BOOL)imageView:(UIImageView*)iv hasImageWithName:(NSString*)imageName
{
    return UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:imageName]) == UIImagePNGRepresentation(iv.image);
}
```

Comment: it would be unwise to generate the hash of the `UIImage`, because `UIImage` is already conform to `Hashable`, it would be like re-inventing the wheel